# How to update particular field in Elasticsearch index?

Tags: elasticsearch

In Elasticsearch I have the following data:

```
"hits": [
      {
        "_index": "traffic",
        "_type": "entry",
        "_id": "922",
        "_score": 1,
        "_source": {
          "Intensity": 0,
          "tId": "9"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "traffic",
        "_type": "entry",
        "_id": "2812",
        "_score": 1,
        "_source": {
          "Intensity": 0,
          "tId": "28"
        }
      }
```

How can I set `Intensity` ea¡qual to 5 for `tId` equal to `28`? Which update query should I write?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **_id** for tId = 28 is **2812**. So:

```
POST traffic/entry/2812/_update
{
    "doc" : {
        "Intensity" : 5
    }
}
```

Source: [Elasticsearch Reference Documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-update.html#_updates_with_a_partial_document)

Comment: But is it possible to Update based on `where tId=28`?

Comment: No, not out-of-the-box. You may use this plugin though: https://github.com/yakaz/elasticsearch-action-updatebyquery

Answer (score 0):

```
client.updateByQuery({
      index : 'traffic',
      type : 'entry',
      body : {
        query : {
          match : {
            tId : 28
          }
        },
        script :
        {'inline':
        'ctx._source.Intensity = params["Intensity"];',
        lang   : 'painless',
        params : {Intensity: 5 }
        }
      }
    }, (err, res) => {
      if (err) {
        reject(err);
      } else {
        resolve(res);
      }
    });
```

For enabling script, you should include `script.inline: true` in elasticsearch.yaml file

Comment: Be careful when enabling scripts: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-scripting-security.html#modules-scripting-security-do-no-weaken